# Blazor (server) can I call cascading parameters and/or injected services anywhere?

Tags: dependency-injection, blazor, blazor-server-side

This seems to work but it may be because of where/how I'm using it. In a random .cs file, not part of a page.razor.cs or similar file, I have the following:

```
[Inject] private ILogger<Register> Logger { get; set; } = default!;

[CascadingParameter] private Task<AuthenticationState> authenticationStateTask { get; set; } = default!;
```

and it works fine - I can use both. Is this valid to do in any code anywhere in the app once main() in program.cs has completed setup? Or is this something that will cause me problems and/or is limited to only certain uses?

Comment: You can for sure do it in a base class .cs inheriting ComponentBase and derive a Razor component from it. If you can do it, I don't see a reason why you couldn't do it elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Inject] and [CascadingParameter] are attributes that can be applied as long as they are referenced.  They're just a special type of class.  They only mean something to an interested party.

In your code where I'm assuming you have nullable set to true [good practice], you are applying the *Null Forgiving* operator [!] to prevent the compiler throwing null warnings at you.

That works as long as `Logger` and `authenticationStateTask` are assigned values before you try and use them.  Within the component/renderer context that's true, but outside that context it's not.

In the component context, dependency injection doesn't happen on instance initialization, as in normal DI: dependencies as not declared in the Ctor.  The Renderer gets all the [inject] attribute properties from the class, gets instances of the required services from the DI container, and assigns them itself after component initialization as part of the *attach* process.  Outside the Renderer/Component process there's no one to do that job, hence no assignment of DI services.

CascadingParameters are passing into the component by the Renderer when it calls `SetParametersAsync` on the component.  Outside that process there's no context to set them, so the properties will remain at their initial values.

Note:

In the component context:

1. You can guarantee `Logger` is not null as the Renderer will throw an exception if it can't get the service.
2. You can't guarantee `authenticationStateTask` will not be null.  I do this to double check.  Parameters values are applied in `SetParametersAsync` before `OnInitialized` is called, and `OnInitialized` runs to completion before any render events happen.

```cs
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(authenticationStateTask);
    }
```

**Null Forgiving**

*Null Forgiving* basically says "I know what I'm doing, shut up!", so you don't get all those warnings.

You can `!` any [Inject] property as the Renderer will throw an exception if it can't get the service.

This in a Razor component:

```cs
@inject WeatherForecastProvider ForecastService
```

gets compiled to this:

```cs
#nullable disable
        [global::Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.InjectAttribute] private WeatherForecastProvider ForecastService { get; set; }
#nullable restore
```

which is basically the same thing.

**Cascading Parameters**

My rule on cascading parameters is to `!` and check for null if they are `fixed` and therefore do not change after `OnInitialized` is run.

Otherwise, treat them as nullable.  They could be changed on the next render cycle.

Comment: Ok... so if I'm not part of a component initialization, how do I get the values for them? Also, are all [Inject] variables guaranteed to be non-null and it's only the [CascadingParameter] variables I have to verify? And is it best practice to declare not null even for [CascadingParameter] as long as I do the check in OnInitialized()? As always, your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Second question : Yes, as long as you are using a component in the Renderer context.

Comment: Third question: see my updated answer

Comment: First question.  A question: in what context are you trying to use a component?  A class  implementing `IComponent` [which is the real definition of a Component] should only be used within the render context.

Comment: Forget first question - that was me thinking wrong. Thanks for the updates. I'll follow that parctice.